# How to access WKWebView content in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I need to check wether content of the WKWebView HTML content contains a certain string. How can I do it? I have not fount any content or data attribute on it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Method 1:
Do it in Objective-C

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:wkwebview.URL usedEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"string to find"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    //found
}
```

Method 2: Do it in JQuery

```
NSString *js = @"var htmlString = $('body').html().toString();
var index = htmlString.indexOf('string to find');
if (index != -1) {alert('found')}";

[wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: The first method is not awesome. It hits the network again. And it blocks because it is a synchronous call. It also does not actually 'execute' the page. It will just search on whatever the server returned, so it fails on dynamic pages.